# Log4j2/JPA/Hibernate logging is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, orm, log4j2

I can't make hibernate log messages with log4j2. It logs only INFO and WARN. On the other side HikariCP works perfectly with this config. Here is the pom.xml:

```
    ... <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency> ...
```

log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <!--<Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug"/>-->
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug"/>
        <Logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari" level="debug" />
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that hibernate is the latest 4.3.7. It uses jboss logging and according to docs it should work fine with log4j2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. Hibernate definitely uses jboss-logging, so the version coming with hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager is 3.1.3.GA and when it gets upgraded to the latest 3.2.0.Final everything has started to work normally.

Answer (score 25):

Hibernate logs with jboss-logging. Now Hibernate 4.3.7.Final uses jboss-logging 3.1.3.GA which does not support any binding with log4j2, **BUT** its last version (3.2.0.Final) [already does](https://wiki.apache.org/logging/Log4j2AndHibernate4), so the only thing you need to do is to add the new one:

```
<!-- HIBERNATE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- HIBERNATE -->
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to exclude. You just need to include the most recent version and it will have precedence to the older one. :) BTW, I just opened a PR for this: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/902

Comment: You're right! indeed I got confused because at the exclusion "artifactId" is placed first and at the dependency is placed second (after the groupId)...thought it was a different group/artifact. Thanks @dadoonet, I'll edit it ;)